# How do i integrate LDAP Auth on Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap

I am currently developing an application and i want to have an LDAP Auth on my login. Can anyone provide me a tutorial link? or just help me how to make it. I dont have any idea how to make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Set up your LDAP Server.By reading your description I think you already have one.

2.You can connect you server by these code.
I bind to the LDAP and search "uniqueMember" attribute.

```
`/**
 *
 */
public static function connLdap(){
    $ldapConfig = Sys::getLdapConfig();//just a config Array
    $ds = ldap_connect($ldapConfig['host']);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    $loginDn = $ldapConfig['adminDn'];
    $passwd = $ldapConfig['passwd'];
    ldap_bind($ds,$loginDn,$passwd);
    return $ds;
}

public static function getPayEmailsLdap(){
    //getAdministrators

    //Connect to LDAP
    $ds = Sys::connLdap();
    //begin to search，need the resource $ds before.
    $res = ldap_search($ds,"cn=yourAddress","(cn=*)",array("uniqueMember"));
    $resInfo = ldap_get_entries($ds,$res);
    $return = array();
    $pattern = '/cn=(.*?),/';
    foreach ($resInfo[0]['uniquemember'] as $v) {
        preg_match($pattern,$v,$matches);
        if($matches){
            $return[] = $matches[1].'@admin.com';
        }
    }
    return $return;
}
```

`